# Parameter to set Guest OS Customization Specification in Ansible

Tags: ansible, vmware

it is possible to create vm from template with **Guest OS customization specification** ?
i using vmware_guest module in ansible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuSm5.png)

My custom spec in vmware:
[image: custom spec in vmware]

Answer (score 0):

this is cannot be happen, api wmware doest have Guest OS Customization, but you can modify each step customization such as VLAN, HOSTNAME, JOIN DOMAIN, ETC.